# Page load function in node js

Tags: node.js

In javascript call "document.ready(funtion({}))" for loading data at once when page is loaded.Is there any alternative funtion in node js?If yes please let me know.If no please sugess me way for,I want to initialize some data on pageload.
Thank you in advance..!

Answer (score 3):

`document` or `window` are not part of JavaScript described in ECMAScript so the `document.addEventListener("load", callback)` (`document.onload = callback;`) or `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callback)` (not `ready` which jQuery provided) are only DOM feature.

DOM is only provided by browser, so there are no DOM in Node.js

If you want set properties and to be sure that properties are setted when a feature is fully loaded you must use the callback provided by each feature of Node.js or Node.js Module.

Example:

```
var http = require("http"),
    response, // You want your response code.
    callback;

http.get({
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: 80,
  path: '/',
  agent: false
}, callback);

callback = function (res) {
  response = res;
  console.log(response); // Here `response` will return an object.
}

console.log(response); // But here, even if code is written after `http.get`, `response ` will return `undefined` because response is used before the callback (same as callback of `addEventListener`) was called.
```